# object name already exists: PUBLIC in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

I have an HSQLDB database (script/log) that I want to read into an In-Memory database. This script has near its top:

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA;
```

which leads to an error. So I tried executing that manually and I don't understand the result. Here's what I did:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why do I get `object name already exists: PUBLIC / Error Code: -5504 / State: 42504`?

Did I not drop the schema correctly or why am I unable to create it?

Answer (score 0):

The PUBLIC schema exists in all new databases. When you drop the PUBLIC schema, an empty version gets recreated automatically. Therefore, you do not need to create the PUBLIC schema.

Comment: So I guess my understanding that a `.script` file from a Standalone database can be run against an In-Memory database to recreate the state of the database is wrong?

Comment: Some statements in the .script file should not be run.